# Javascript regexp matching integer from 1-10 following phrase

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string, which includes but is not limited to

```
string = 'thumbnails-per-row-10-text'
```

I would like to select the number after `thumbnails-per-row-` , which will always be an integer from one to ten.

The regexp I have so far is:

```
value = string.match(/thumbnails-per-row-([1-9]|[10])/)[1]
```

However, this doesn't work as I would expect, as it will match 0 but only match the value of '1' when I am looking to receive the value of '10'.

How can I adjust my regexp to correctly return an integer from 1-10?

Comment: `(10|[1-9])` ..........

Comment: or this `([2-9]|10?)`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I cannot believe `?` was in a blindspot, I urgently need glasses. Apologies

Comment: Why not `/thumbnails-per-row-(\d+)/`? Do you really need to prevent matching 11, or 99?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
/^thumbnails-per-row-(?:(?:[1-9]-)|(?:10-))text$/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bS5dQ6/1)

Using the same methodology, you can expand to match 1-20:

```
/^thumbnails-per-row-(?:(?:[1-9]-)|(?:1[0-9]-)|(?:20-))text$/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bS5dQ6/3)

and so on...

As stated in the comments (Thanks wolf) you can move the `-` out of the inner groups:

```
^thumbnails-per-row-(?:(?:[1-9])|(?:1[0-9])|(?:20))-text$
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer and the demos. This is the answer that will match only from 1-10, and for example not match the first '1' of 11.

Comment: Great answer, but suggest `^thumbnails-per-row-(?:(?:[1-9])|(?:1[0-9])|(?:20))-text$` You do not need the hyphen inside the alteration groups.

Answer (score 4):

Your code does not work since 1 matches `[1-9]`, the regex is happy and ends the search. Put the 10 first as regular expressions will try alternate combinations in the order they are specified:

```
value = string.match(/thumbnails-per-row-(10|[1-9])/)[1] // Output: 10
```

**Edit**:
If you don't want to match values outside that range, require that the second hyphen follows immediately after the number.

```
value = string.match(/thumbnails-per-row-(10|[1-9])-/)[1]
```

Comment: Luckily, for what I am working with the value will only ever be between 1-10. How could I limit that though if I wanted it to return null if the value was over 10?

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. First, `[1-9]` will match the first `1` of `10` and the regex will never reach the `[10]` part.
2. Second, `[10]` will match `0` becase `[]` in regular expressions matches any character inside the brackets - hence `[10]` will be `true` for `1` or `0`.

What you want to do is match against the range `1-9` or the VALUE `10`, putting the `10` first, like so:

```
value = string.match(/thumbnails-per-row-(10|[1-9])/)[1]
```

Comment: Yeah sorry was halfway through answering :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your regexp to the following:
`value = string.match(/([1-9]|[10])/)[1]`

Works when I test it in [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/)

Edit: Nevermind. Apparently it doesn't work in console. You need to change it to:
`value = string.match(/thumbnails-per-row-(10|[1-9]|)/)[1]`